# Recognizing a game that someone is playing without chatting(discord bot python)

Tags: python, discord

(discord bot python)

The code is that if someone chats anything, if the person is playing Overwatch, he or she will be promoted to the role of Gamer, and if not, he or she will be deleted or nothing will happen. But I am looking for a way to recognize the game that is playing without chatting. Can someone help me?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    man = message.author.activity.name
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Gamer")
    if man == "Overwatch":
        await message.author.add_roles(role)
    else:
        await message.author.remove_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`on_member_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update) event is triggered whenever a member changes their activities:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after)
    role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name="Gamer")
    if before.activities != after.activities:
        name = "Overwatch"
        before_name = any(activity.name for activity in before.activities)
        after_name = any(activity.name for activity in after.activities)
        if not before_name and after_name:
            await after.add_roles(role)
        elif before_name and not after_name:
            await after.remove_roles(role)
```

Comment: What import should I use?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to look into the [`on_member_update()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update) event. Something like so:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(prev, cur):
    role = discord.utils.get(cur.guild.roles, name="Gamer")
    games = ["overwatch", "rocket league", "minecraft"]
    # make sure game titles are lowercase

    if cur.activity and cur.activity.name.lower() in games:
            await cur.add_roles(role)

    # only add the rest if you want them to have the role for the duration of them
    # playing a game
    elif prev.activity and prev.activity.name.lower() in games and not cur.activity:
            if role in cur.roles: # check they already have the role, as to not throw an error
                await cur.remove_roles(role)
```

---

**References:**

- [`on_member_update()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update)
- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)
- [`Activity.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Activity.name)
- [`Member.remove_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.remove_roles)
- [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)

Comment: What import should I use?

Comment: No more imports other than the ones you currently have are necessary. As long as you have discord.py installed, you'll be fine.

Comment: Such an error occurs when I change my status
```
Ignoring exception in on_member_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Godster\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Godster/Desktop/sadas/sadas.py", line 164, in on_member_update
    if cur.activity.name.lower() in games:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```
How can i solve this?

Comment: @g0dst3r Edited my answer